# Set the first column of pandas dataframe as header

Tags: python, pandas

This is my output DataFrame from reading an excel file

I would like my first column to be index/header

```
     one               Entity
0    two                   v1
1  three                 Prod
2   four  2015-05-27 00:00:00
3   five  2018-04-27 00:00:00
4    six                 Both
5  seven                   id
6  eight                hello
```

Answer (score 3):

**To Set the first column of pandas data frame as header**

> set "header=1" while reading file

eg: `df = pd.read_csv(inputfilePath, header=1)`

> set **skiprows=1** while reading the file

eg: `df = df.read_csv(inputfilepath, skiprows=1)`

> set **iloc[0]** in dataframe

eg: `df.columns = df.iloc[0]`

I hope this will help.

Comment: The problem with the last one, is that it remains as values, and i dont like it

Answer (score 2):

One way is using `T` twice

```
df=df.T.set_index(0).T
```